# Handling multiple operation on oncomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

I have a JQ grid having search results. In that grid, I have a checkbox at column level. on click on that checkbox a rich modalpanel opens. In that panel I have a rich picklist and a button. If nothing is selected from picklist and clicked on button, I have to display a error message and keep the panel as it is. And if something is selected from picklist I have to hide the panel and reload the grid. Problem is when I don't select anything from picklist and click on button, I am able to display error message but in background grid is getting reloaded.

My code for button is

```
    <a:commandLink styleClass="btn green-btn save-btn fr" style="margin: 10px; align:right;" onclick="updateLOB()" action="#{assetManager.updateLOB()}" reRender="distTypesPanel"
                            oncomplete="#{facesContext.messages.hasNext() == false ? 'Richfaces.hideModalPanel(\'updateLOBPanel\');' : 'Richfaces.showModalPanel(\'updateLOBPanel\');'};
                                        document.getElementById('lobMasterCheckBox').checked=false;gridReload();">
  <span> Save </span> 
                 </a:commandLink>
```

It is bit tricky to handle this. Can someone suggest me any idea how to do? Is there a way to get selected list from picklist ?

Comment: always provide your rendered HTML rather than your code ...

Comment: your button is triggering postback and grid gets reloaded ... you need to prevent postabck on your button on certain condition..

Comment: @patel.milanb.. Thanks for the response..:) Resolved the issue by using onHide tag of the rich modal panel

Comment: @Sanjay You can post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, so everybody knows that you are not looking for further answers.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution..!

Instead of reloading the grid in  oncomplete tag of the button, I used onshow and onHide tag of richmodal panel. OnHide of panel, I am reloading the grid now.So if there are error messages, modalpanel will be there on UI and grid won't reload as I am calling gridReload in onHise property of modal panel.